The worst possible move
The "worst possible move" must have the following characteristics:

With one exception, all legal moves would mate the opponent.
The player to move makes that exceptional move.
After that, all legal responses by the opponent are checkmate.

Does such a position exist?
I suspect probably both players would need to have a king in their last line, nearly mated by a line of pawns.

The relevant question is linked by Rewan, but was badly titled so I have renamed it. Gray Sheep's question is clearly much more focused: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41822/move-forcing-opponent-to-checkmate-in-response
